# How do I render the word "Vǫlundarkviða" with bookman and xelatex?

Tags: fonts, xetex

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Thought this was unnecessary with XeLaTeX
\begin{document}
Vǫlundarkviða
\end{document}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

As you can see, the second letter is missing. Also, I feel like `fontenc` should not be there. How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an OpenType clone of Bookman, for instance TeX Gyre Bonum.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Bonum}

\begin{document}

Vǫlundarkviða

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, thanks. Any idea why `bookman` did not?

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard Because it's a legacy font and doesn't have the glyphs (they're not in the T1 encoding).

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought ð and ǫ would always both be present, but apparently not.